# How to register a default login user?

Tags: php, symfony, bundler, easyadmin3

**Context: ** I have 2 associated entities, being "persona" and "ingreso".

I tried to capture the logged in user and send it as a default variable in the form:

```
    TextField::new('person','Person')
        ->formatValue(function ($value) {
            return $value = $this->getUser();
        })
        ->hideOnForm()
```

*But:* This arrives as a Null value in the database.

**This is why I try to capture the user and save it from the entity, but I don't know a correct way to do it**.

Answer (score 0):

You are using ->hideOnForm, which remove the field in your form, so nothing is sent concerning **person**.

There is multiple way to do what you want, including similar answer such has having a hidden select with your user, however I do not consider it a good solution.

Have you considered using Event ?

In your case you could either listen using Doctrine events or with EasyAdmin Events.

[Symfony events](https://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher.html)

```
<?php

namespace App\EventSubscriber;

use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Event\BeforeEntityUpdatedEvent;
//... other imports

class EasyAdminSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private $tokenStorage

    public function __construct(TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage)
    {
        $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage
    }
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [BeforeEntityUpdatedEvent => ['beforeEntityUpdatedEvent'], ];
    }

    public function beforeEntityUpdatedEvent(BeforeEntityUpdatedEvent $event)
    {
        $entity = $event->getEntityInstance();
        
        if ($entity instanceof YourEntityYouWantToListenTo) {
            $entity->setPerson($this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser());
        }

    }
```